# ES6 Map an object to a decorator

Tags: javascript, dictionary, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, decorator

I'd like to map an object with properties (key) to a decorator (value). I'd like to use a Weak Map if possible. I have a solution that is working using a string, which is fine except that Weak Maps do not accept strings as keys. Is this possible with a Map or a WeakMap?

```
'use strict';

class Accordion {

    constructor() {}

}

let Decorators = new Map();

Decorators.set({nodeName: 'tag-name-here', component: 'accordion'}, (client) => { return new Accordion(client) });

class Client {

    constructor() {

        let key =  {nodeName: 'tag-name-here', component: 'accordion'}
        let decorator;

        if (Decorators.has(key)) {

            decorator = Decorators.get(key)(this);

        }

        console.log(decorator); //undefined, unless I use a string as a key.
    }
}

new Client();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because different instance of key: `{nodeName: 'tag-name-here', component: 'accordion'}` will map to a new memory location each time, so you won't be able to get your desired value this way. To make it work, you have to set it to a new variable, so that your code looks like the following:

```js
'use strict';

class Accordion {

    constructor() {}

}

let Decorators = new Map();

const key = {nodeName: 'tag-name-here', component: 'accordion'};
Decorators.set(key, (client) => { return new Accordion(client) });

class Client {

    constructor() {
        let decorator;

        if (Decorators.has(key)) {

            decorator = Decorators.get(key)(this);

        }

        console.log(decorator); // this should return an object
    }
}

new Client();
```